# How can I stop ReSharper from adding an unwanted newline after a line preceded by a comment?

Tags: resharper

I sometimes use comments to "group" members like this:

```
// unary operators:
public static readonly string Not = Create(nameof(Not));
public static readonly string Negate = Create(nameof(Negate), "-");

// mathematical operators:
public static readonly string Add = Create(nameof(Add), "+");
public static readonly string Subtract = Create(nameof(Subtract), "-");
```

Quick format will insert a newline after the line that is preceded by a comment:

```
// unary operators:
public static readonly string Not = Create(nameof(Not));

public static readonly string Negate = Create(nameof(Negate), "-");

// mathematical operators:
public static readonly string Add = Create(nameof(Add), "+");

public static readonly string Subtract = Create(nameof(Subtract), "-");
```

Where do I turn this off?

To me it makes sense for ReSharper to insert such a newline if the comment were an XML doc (`/// <summary>...`), but for regular comments (only two slashes) I don't want that.

I'd rather turn it off altogether if there is no separate option for two-slash comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked ReSharper support [the same question](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000473924-How-can-I-stop-ReSharper-from-adding-an-unwanted-newline-after-a-line-preceded-by-a-comment-?page=1#community_comment_115000401204) and they provided me with the answer:

> Please change the following option - ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Blank Lines | Around fields to 0.

I didn't think that option was affecting my fields because there's also a `Around single-line fields` option. Turns out comments are considered part of the field, which is why that option had no effect.